# filtering and sorting divs

Tags: javascript, filtering

I have been looking for a robust and simple way to sort my casestudies but after a couple of hours and a search of stack overflow i could not find a way to filter casestudies the way I want.

Basically I will give each casestudy three categories (year produced, type of project and name) using css classes, for example the markup would look something like this

```
<div class="name1 home 2013"></div>
<div class="name2 work 2012"></div>
<div class="name3 home 2012"></div>
<div class="name4 charity 2012"></div>
<div class="name5 home 2010"></div>
<div class="name6 work 2007"></div>
```

Then I want to have buttons so you can choose which category you want to sort the casestudies by. So something like.

```
<div class="button" id="year">Sort by Year</div>
<div class="button" id="alpha">sort Alphabetically</div>
<div class="button" id="type">sort by type</div>
```

This is where I am getting stuck. What javascript function can i create so that if you click the button "sort by year" it will create a mark up that looks like this. eg sorting all the casestudies in to divs with casestudies of the same year.

```
<div>
   <div class="name1 home 2013"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="name2 work 2012"></div>
<div class="name3 home 2012"></div>
<div class="name4 charity 2012"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="name5 home 2010"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="name6 work 2007"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That content looks like a better fit for a table than a generic div. That would probably make it easier to sort as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use data attributes to make the filtering easier.

```
<div class="name1 home" data-year="2013">2013</div>
<div class="name2 work" data-year="2012">2012</div>
<div class="name3 home" data-year="2012">2012</div>
<div class="name4 charity" data-year="2012">2012</div>
<div class="name5 home" data-year="2010">2010</div>
<div class="name6 work" data-year="2007">2007</div>
```

The using JQuery and array.map (could be replaced with a foreach if you want older browser support)

```
var studies = $('[data-year]')

studies.map(function(index, el) {
    var $el = $(el)
    year = $el.attr('data-year')
    if($('#' + year).length == 0){
        $(document.body).append(
            $('<div>').attr('id', year)
            .css('margin-bottom', '20px')
        )
    }

    $('#' + year).append(el)
 })
```

what this does is take all the elements with a data-year attribute, foreach element check to see if a div with the id of that elements year exists. If it doesn't create one and append it to the body. Then it appends the element into the year container.

[see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DPxWu/3/)

Comment: Thanks that looks great! Also so if I wanted to do the same with with the type of project can i write data-project="project"

Comment: Yeah you can do that. you can also make it so this map function works on any data-attribute by passing it as a parameter and changing `year = $el.attr('data-year')` to look up the data-attribute according to the parameter.

Comment: If you're using HTM5 data attributes, why not use [jQuery's `data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/)?

Comment: In my total noobness I was not aware of this. Thanks +1 to use them.